# PyQt6 / Matplotlib - multiple FigureCanvasQTAgg using one single Figure object

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt6

I have an application where the user can open / close many windows containing different plots. At first I attempted to use a new Matplotlib Figure for each window but I had trouble releasing the memory when closing a window with a plot.

An option I am looking at is using a separate FigureCanvasQTAgg for each window and having them share one single Figure. The problem then becomes that if I clear and replot the figure for one window it affects all others.

My question is the following - is there a way to "freeze" a FigureCanvasQTAgg once it has been drawn so that it is not updated when the Figure is cleared / replotted?

One idea I had was to use an EventFilter to catch and stop the paint event for the FigureCanvasQTAgg once it has been drawn so that it is no longer repainted. However I have not been able to make it work. I have not used EventFilter before so I may be doing it incorrectly.

Here is the code, using a simple example with 2 windows using one single Figure. When the second window is plotted the first window gets cleared, which is what I want to avoid. If anyone can spot what's wrong or suggest another way to prevent the first window to be redrawn when the second one is plotted it would be great.

```
import sys
import random
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self,fig):

        self.paint_enabled = True

        super().__init__(fig)

        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):

        if object == self and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.Paint and not self.paint_enabled:

            return False

        return super().eventFilter(object,event)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xdata = list(range(50))
ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(50)]

ax.plot(xdata,ydata)

c1 = Canvas(fig)
c1.move(100,100)
c1.draw()
c1.show()

c1.paint_enabled = False

def second_plot():

    ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(50)]

    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xdata,ydata)

    c2 = Canvas(fig)

    c2.move(600,600)
    c2.draw()
    c2.show()

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.setSingleShot(True)
timer.timeout.connect(second_plot)
timer.start(1000)

app.exec()
```

Comment: First of all, such a "procedural" approach is not normally suggested for complex and dynamical situations like this. Besides, if you had memory issues when closing, it means that the figures are *not* destroyed when closed, they are just closed/hidden. You should override the [`closeEvent()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) method and call [`deleteLater()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) (and remember to remove any other reference to that object). Also, you don't need to install an event filter on `self`, just override [`event()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event).

Comment: Thanks. After some consideration I think I will abandon using Matplotlib in favor of PyQtGraph. The performance it is so much better + I won't have any issues with memory.